# proposal : allowing multiple upvotes

Tags: feature-request, voting, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [cast multiple votes with cost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/cast-multiple-votes-with-cost)
>   [Should we have a small number of Supervotes per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day)

In a [recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807161/how-can-i-quickly-search-directories-without-filefind-module-in-perl/1808213#1808213), `brian_d_foy` said :

> I've often wished that Stackoverflow would let us spend more than one vote on answers

... and I agree, so here's a modest proposal -- for really exceptional answers, allow people a second up-vote, but at an expense to their own reputation.  To prevent abuse, you could make it cost <strike>2</strike> 11 reputation (or more), so people can't use multiple accounts to try to game the system.

If it's something that would only be used for truly great answers, I could even see spending <strike>5</strike> 20 reputation (which is more than <strike>0.5%</strike> 2% of my current rep on any of the sites) to give them a +2 upvote.

Of course, I have no idea what it'd take to actually implement something like this, and there might be other social issues that I hadn't considered, but I just thought I'd toss it out there for discussion.

*update* : okay, I should've verified the amount of reputation gained by upvotes.  My goal was to make it cost 2 to 5 times the benefit gained from an upvote, so I screwed up.

Comment: I clicked the downvote button twice, but it didn't work. :/

Comment: duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/cast-multiple-votes-with-cost

Answer (score 5):

**One man, one vote**.

Otherwise, the score is utterly meaningless: a +6 answer might have garnered the approval of 6x more people than the +1 answer... or it might just have one really dedicated fan.

Comment: Which is why I said a 'second upvote', not 'additional upvotes'.  I probably should've made that more clear.

Comment: Same problem, with slightly reduced severity. Now the +6 answer needed 3 people with rep to burn, vs. the +3 answer that had the same number of conservative up-voters.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Chicago, and even **I** see the problems with this. One vote per person per post is just right -- any more, and we are open to all kinds of gaming. Not to mention screwing some people into the rep cap even more quickly than normal (*cough*Jon Skeet*cough*).

Answer (score 1):

hmm... spending 2 reputation for providing 10 reputation... no, I don't see any way to game the system

Comment: crap ... should've looked at the docs on rep given for upvotes to verify amounts before I posted

Comment: You should try using the system a little, seeing how it works, before proposing new features.

Comment: seems like he's used it "a little".  he probably ought to use it "a little more"... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139598?tab=accounts#sort-top