# Why is voting limited to 1 per person per question or answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we have a small number of Supervotes per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day)

I understand the limit to the number of votes a person can place in a day: [Why are there voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/why-are-there-voting-limits) (both for operational and psychological reasons).

But given that there -are- such daily voting limits, wouldn't it then be reasonable to allow one **to vote more than once** for a given question or answer? In the extreme, to allow 30 votes for one answer (and then no more voting at all that day)? One vote here, a 5 for a really good answer there.

If the possibility of 30 at any one time seems excessive, then how about a max limit of 2 votes at a time or maybe even 5.

I offer this as a suggestion because it is often so much desired to give an extra vote to a really good answer/question (from comments one reads all the time).

Comment: as a `feature-request` this is possibly a dupe of one or more of:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31177/proposal-allowing-multiple-upvotes  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/cast-multiple-votes-with-cost http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day

Comment: @Daniel: possibly, but at the time of those questions was there a daily limit to # of votes?

Comment: The daily limit was constituted very early on in Stack Overflow's life, so yes - those questions were asked when people only had 30 daily votes.