# Upvote twice by giving your rep

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow users to cast multiple votes with increasing cost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/allow-users-to-cast-multiple-votes-with-increasing-cost)

A lot of times, people are saying in comments "If I could upvote this twice, I totally would".

Let's give them this possibility. However, to keep this fair, the second upvote will take one rep point (or more) off the upvoter.

It's a really nice way to say "hey, I really love this answer/question so much that I give you my rep".

I know about the bounty system, but they're not really the same. Bounties are constraining. They require you to wait for 2 days, they have a minimum of 50 rep, etc. This proposal is lighter and more spontaneous.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much a micro-bounty?

Comment: See: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @hammar http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156140/upvote-twice-by-giving-your-rep#comment449264_156141

Comment: If I could downvote this twice, I totally would.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this. It's called a bounty.

Sure, 50 rep is a bit more than 10 rep - but if the answer is awesome enough...

Comment: Bounties are quite limited. Setting up a bounty requires you to wait for 2 days, it has a minimum of 50 rep, etc. My proposal is lighter and more spontaneous.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine As a result, your proposal would make certain kinds of reputation scams quite easy.

Comment: @AndrewBarber care to elaborate?

Comment: Additionally, the bounty only allows you to award an answer. Sure, it attracts more attention to the question, but that doesn't necessarily guarantee more upvotes.