# Should we just move the joke questions from StackOverflow to Meta?

Tags: discussion

Lord knows plenty of waffle and pony jokes seem to find their home here, and moving the joke questions from SO to here would end the debate about broken windows on SO (as far as joke questions are concerned).

Answer (score 11):

No. Meta has enough joke questions.

Comment: Jokes should be domain specific. For instance "Do OS CEO's secretly pander to a homosexual audience by wearing phallic cashmere turtleneck sweaters?" is obviously a SuperUser question because it fits the 'general computing' domain whereas "Are you a dinosaur programmer?" is obviously StackOverflow related. Meta is **strictly** reserved for jokes about unicorns and statistical analysis of John Skeets presence on the trilogy.

Answer (score 8):

What makes you think we want them?

Answer (score 5):

No, not here.  [What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) was migrated here once and Jeff moved it back.  They don't really fit the intended purpose of meta.

Answer (score 3):

What sort of joke questions are there on SO? I only see *stupid* questions, like "what's the worst programming mistake you've ever made".  That's not funny, that's a solicitation for stories (and personally, I'm happy to get my fill of those from [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com) and [Reddit](http://reddit.com/r/programming)).

Comment: [What is your best programmer joke?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)

Comment: @Bill: that's just one question though, not to mention it is currently locked :)

Comment: There was a cartoon one too, but I'm sure that's also locked.  Now that you mention it...

Comment: @Bill - I'm pretty sure I saw the cartoon one get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they should go to the [**third place**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) that will eventually appear.

Comment: I'm an unsociable programmer; I would never go there :P

Comment: Ah, then it's probably __exactly__ where you want them to go.

Comment: Oh, great. We haven't even launched the "third place" yet and you're already deciding on how to crap it up.

Comment: @Robert, so if it doesn't allow subjective, discussiony stuff, then what would it possible have?

Comment: @Lance: It would be yet another dumping ground for poor, orphaned questions without a home.

Comment: the third place is chat: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/web-based-irc-for-the-trilogy

Answer (score 0):

If not Meta then somewhere. They are one of the reasons that I felt the urge to respond to a closed topic. I feel it sets a hypocritical view of closed topics when viewing the question list.

Comment: ??? You can't reply to a closed question; that's what "closed" means.

Comment: @Ether: he probably meant he added a comment. I had someone arguing with me in comments about closing a subjective question the other day.

Comment: Yes, you can comment although I tend not to make a point of arguing as it tends to desend into petty insults.

Comment: Aye, those arguments are rather tiresome, especially when the core argument is always "why does Stack Overflow HATE FUN??!?!?!?!"

Answer (score 0):

A unicorn, a pony and a waffle are having a drink at SO Towers, when the barman leans over and says to the pony: 'Why the long face?'.

...

I'll get my coat.

Comment: Don't bother.  We'll ship it to you.  __OUT.  NOW.__

Comment: *A doctor, a lawyer, and a rabbi log into stack overflow...* – Kip Jul 9 '09 at 22:00 *The bartender looks at them and goes "Sorry, you guys are not programming related."* – TheTXI Jul 9 '09 at 22:04 – [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/is-the-down-voting-most-all-answers-that-arent-yours-pattern-considered-harm/4014#4014)

Answer (score 0):

Not meta, it's noisy enough already. What about notserious.[SOFU].com, suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53827/notserious-sofu-com-for-jokes-discussions-et-al)?

Answer (score 0):

I thought Apocalyptic Defense would have been a nice dumping ground.. But, alas, it's not meant to be.