# notserious.[SOFU].com for jokes, discussions et al

Tags: feature-request

While waffles and unicorn are sometimes amusing, they are also noise shadowing serious issues. So I suggest a separate place for them, with the user-option to still display its content to be shown at meta for "relaxation" or similar.

(that's my reply to a [similar request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53782/should-we-just-move-the-joke-questions-from-stackoverflow-to-meta))

Comment: google the "7 stages of usenet"...

Comment: I've seen great humor here, but I'm tired of the in-jokes (waffles, unicorns, whatever). Great for the oldies (I suppose), not so nice for the newbies.

Comment: related: [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/146482)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only purpose for this that I can see is getting the non-serious stuff out of chat, comments, Programmers SE and Meta SO. This would be a lose/lose situation, because

- the only value in the sites comes from getting all the non-serious stuff moved
- you'll never get **all** the non-serious stuff moved, so there's no value to be had
- by eating up people's time and energy for no useful purpose, these sites would actively hurt the "real" sites
- the people who do play along will get annoyed at people who don't, and vice versa; we already have one eternal war going on courtesy of the subjective/objective camps, we don't need another one

Not to mention that these sites wouldn't exactly be making positive contributions to the general fund of human knowledge. And yes, I realize you initially proposed this before chat and Programmers existed.

Comment: Yes, you make a perfect point. Maybe the less-abusive [Fourth place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/146482) idea is an improvement...