# Marking questions/answers as not serious and a user option to filter them out

Tags: feature-request

Maybe instead of sending unserious questions and sometimes funny answers (which unfortunately may receive more upvotes than serious answers) to [another place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53827/notserious-sofu-com-for-jokes-discussions-et-al) those who post them should check a "not serious"-checkbox which those currently not seeking distraction could then filter out (temporarily).

Tagging questions with [not-serious] would be one way, but there are sometimes answers to serious question which are not exactly spam/noise but still distract from serious answers, especially if upvoted.

Comment: Add [fun] to your ignored tags.  And downvote not-serious answers, after 3 downvotes it will get greyed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not serious, please don't ask it.

*That's* the solution

Comment: it's not for me to post non-serious stuff but to get the noise away from SOFU and meta

Comment: My answer was not directed at you, but at the suggestion. A better solution to get the noise away is to refrain from generating it

Comment: Why did the chicken cross the playground?  To get to the other slide.  Now, there's a lame joke in the comments, and neither you nor Tobias put it there.