# Should you be allowed to downvote the competition?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The answer to tactical downvoting problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem)

I was reading [this post](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1472249) on hacker news. In particular people seemed to be very discouraged about idea they are getting downvotes by competing answerers.

Think about it as anti-sportsmanship. It is clear this is not a super-common practice. Obviously on meta this is a bit more common than on SO.

It is also clear that it leaves a [bad taste](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/is-the-down-voting-most-all-answers-that-arent-yours-pattern-considered-harm).

Should we look at introducing a system that stops people from downvoting the competition in certain cases? If so what are the cases? If not why?

Comment: Yes, but look who his competition was, he wrote [the book](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stackoverflow-reputation-fast/51285#51285) on it.

Comment: @Lance, Yerp the concept would be some for adding inherit protection so these kind of tactics don't work - but its a really valid point that the community has corrected and compensated for this behavior

Comment: Sorry, but I was pretty sure we'd been down this road before. Possible duplicate of [The answer to tactical downvoting problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem) Also a few others?

Answer (score 6):

> Should we look at introducing a system that stops people from downvoting the competition in certain cases? If so what are the cases? If not why?

I think we have to go with no.

Because some questions attract few experts, and we *need* them to *both* provide the correct answer and down mod erroneous answers.

So we just have to depend on peer pressure to deal with the problem.

---

I have seen evidence of the behavior in what appears to be tactical application a few times, so it *is* an issue, but I think that the cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: We could theoretically run a few scripts to isolate the cases of tactical downvoting and then send warnings to repeat offenders. or freeze accounts.

Comment: What's the metric that can tell a real expert downvoting the duffers from a wannabe trying to promote his own answer at the expense of others? It would seem to be an AI complete problem.

Comment: Somebody that does this say on 25% of the questions they answer early in the questions lifecycle would be a pretty safe bet (with added weight to timing - eg. when most people have 0-1 votes this has the most impact)

Comment: Ah...that'll catch the pathological cases, anyway. Might be computationally expensive, though.

Comment: You can do it in retrospect once a week or once a day. You don't even have to change the rules, you can simply undo their downvotes and put them in the sin bin for a week (of course we would have to look at each case indevidually) but in reality there are a very small number of bad seeds.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, it is a well-established convention that a down-vote on meta means simply that someone does not support or agree with your suggestion. Agreed, it can sting a little bit — nobody wants others to disagree with them. But user have gone *way* out of their way to post frequent comments as to what the significance (or insignificance) of the down-vote means.

As far as other systems go, rather than discouraging or dis-allowing down-votes, we should, instead, **encourage people to understand the insignificance of being down-voted** and *not* to take it personally. It is, in the end, meant to be a helpful indication that you might be wrong about something.

The alternative is to treat the mundane (no votes at all) and the incorrect (down-votes) as the same thing. That would be much worse than worrying about hurting someone's feelings.

**Suggested reading:**

Answer to: [Down-Votes Appear to be Pure Evil](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31842/downvotes-appear-to-be-pure-evil/31844#31844) 
Answer to: [Why are people afraid of down-votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21080/why-are-people-afraid-of-downvotes/21086#21086)