# Why not allow downvote only with at least an anonymous comment?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Leaving an anonymous comment when voting.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/leaving-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting)  
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

People downvote with no comments, gives no idea what is wrong with an answer or question. If revealing the identity of downvoter is the concern, please at least allow a comment for downvote anonymously.

Comment: Content-free comment

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/leaving-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting

Comment: Did you just skip that box with all those Related questions when posting?

Comment: Is this going to come up weekly now?

Comment: On SO, you've been downvoted 4 times in two months. You have no answers with a score less than 0, meaning that every single downvote had at least one other upvote to offset it. I wouldn't sweat it too much. Post for post, you're doing OK.

Comment: @JohnRudy I hope it does come up weekly.  I get tired of seeing people downvote things for stupid reasons.  I don't think there should be anonymous commnets, I think it should post the names of people who downvote.

Comment: Can you please express uour opinion on marking question as duplicate at the following link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219750/is-it-correct-to-mark-these-two-questions-as-a-duplicate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We already provide a `<div>` reminder when voting down, to users below 2000 reputation:

[image]

> please consider leaving a comment if you think this post can be improved

Comment: Something like a list of radio buttons would be better.

Answer (score 6):

Requiring people to do things **will. Never. Work.** You **cannot** require people to leave comments when they downvote:

1. This creates spam when someone gives a really bad answer. Do we need 20 comments saying "Your answer sucks" or would one comment with 20 upvotes serve the same purpose (with a lot less flooding of the comment thread)?
2. There's no way to prevent people from leaving useless junk comments (like "asfdsgjhadsgasfsd" or "+1 great answer") to avoid having to explain their downvotes.
3. Most people simply **don't care enough**.

Comment: And why should I have to justify my vote to anyone, whether it be an upvote or a downvote? Kind of defeats the purpose of voting, does it not?

Answer (score 2):

I always try to down-vote with a comment, which I think helps the community. However enforcing someone to leave a comment (even if 'anonymous') may not yield meaningful message. It probably discourages down-voting.

A down-voter is getting a hit of -1, that 'sacrifice' should mean that they are not likely to be down-voting for fun or abusing.

The current situation of using a reminder is sufficient (at least that's how I feel).

Answer (score 1):

My main objection is that the solution to the problems of anonymity is not more anonymity.

Consider this scenario: this system would allow you to leave an anonymous comment where you currently can't so you'll likely encourage downvotes just so people can leave anonymous comments.

Comment: And then people can retract their downvotes in the fraction-of-a-second-change-your-mind-time-that-seriously-needs-to-be-lengthened-Jeff-I-hope-you're-reading-this and get their 1 rep back.