# Is there any kind of incentives to leave a reason for downvoting?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)
>   [Proposal: Require anonymous comment with downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31302/proposal-require-anonymous-comment-with-downvotes)

I asked a question  today and it was downvoted by someone within five minutes! No reason given. Personally I think downvoting without giving a reason is pointless and rude. You're causing the poster to lose 2 points.  I believe my question was clear enough. If there's another reason and you don't tell me about it, I have learned ZERO from you and I lost 2 points and you lost one point. So who's benefiting?

Is there any kind of incentives in the current system to leave a reason for downvoting? Maybe the downvoter should lose more points for downvoting without a reason than with a reason. This means the current -1 should increase.

Comment: We've thrashed this to death many times. See 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59736/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60877/ the comments on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31302/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30066/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32226/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31842/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/ and probably others

Comment: The question under discussion appears to be [Have Visual Studio 2008 run solution upon startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560526/have-visual-studio-2008-run-solution-upon-startup).

Comment: I noticed that downvote when it first happened and was surprised, but in general bribing people to leave comments for every downvote isn't going to end well (dmckee's dozen links on the topic cover why)

Comment: FWIW, you didn't ask a clear question and didn't bother clarifying it when answers started showing up that didn't meet your needs. Not that you should've needed a comment *or* a down-vote to tell you this, but...

Comment: @Shog9: If the question wasn't clear, then state that fact. Yes, that needs to be clear. Plus it was downvoted BEFORE my first comment showed up. Furthermore, don't conclude that my question wasn't clear just because one answer is having many comments. The answer was good but I was having another issue. Not that the answer wasn't clear. Your whole logic leading to your conclusion is flawed.

Comment: @Shog9: At the end, I STILL don't know why you think my question wasn't clear. You might genuinely think it's not clear or you were biased from the answers and comments you have read.

Comment: @Tony: so *why* are you soliciting comments? Why should I state something I consider obvious and you disbelieve? What purpose is there to such effort, if it produces only discord?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when somebody downvotes my answer and leaves a reason (because of an inaccuracy, misstatement, etc), I correct it, and the downvoter changes it to an upvote.

Comment: So is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are many people who spend most of their time voting and moderating questions rather than asking or answering. They see this as their role and it is perfectly valid. They may go over many questions during a given period and may feel it is necessary to just mark it down rather than give an explanation for every down vote.

There are also people who just want to give their opinion by down-voting. This is also a valid use of the system. They may feel your question doesn't warrant an explanation.

In both cases it's just the community giving their opinion of **your question** and not a personal attack. 5 minutes is a long time on SO (not sure if that is the site you are referring to) so it's not like someone just waiting to down-vote your question.