# Add another type of action other than closing if purpose is moving a question out of front page

Tags: feature-request, voting, closed-questions

I have read the comments from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62191/questions-getting-closed-too-fast-within-hours-give-it-some-time-to-live) which gave me another proposal. So some people are 'annoyed' if some type of questions are on the front page. Is this a real problem? SO gets a lot of questions that the front page is a moving list.

If you want the question out of the front page, have a voting system for moving it instead of closing it.

A lot of people do not get the fact that a closed question is basically a signal to users NOT to bother adding more comments or answers to the question. A real DISSERVICE to the poster who is seeking a badly needed answer. A lot of people do not know about re-opening a question or not even care to offer any more help. (Why waste time with a closed questions. Let me run to the new ones)

Having a single action, closing, is killing some good questions. Have some other actions like moving questions to another pile or away from the front page. Yeah I know about the bounty system. You lose the points even if you didn't get any answers. It's discouraging to use it unless you really need an answer.

Comment: Tony, people aren't closing your questions to get them off the front page. They are closing them for the reasons that they give when the vote to close. Recently that has meant as a duplicate of *literary* a dozen previous (long and long-winded) discussions here on meta.

Answer (score 7):

Closing is not about whether or not a question is appropriate for the front page, it is about whether or not it is appropriate for the site at all.

A separate but related issue. If a *question* is not appropriate for the front page, then it is **not** appropriate for the site at all.

On Stack Overflow, all content is first tier. There isn't a section for good questions and a section for "off topic" questions. There are **only** good questions. Anything else *should* be removed and closed.

> A lot of people do not get the fact that a closed question is basically a signal to users NOT to bother adding more comments or answers to the question.

That is *literally* the purpose of closing questions. When I close something as a duplicate, or off topic, or subjective, I am saying that this questions does **not** belong and should **not** be answered or commented on.

Adding a "move off front page" action implies that it is *acceptable* to have content which is *not good enough* to be presentable. We don't have tiers. It's got to be good enough or it's got to go.

Answer (score 6):

A closed question isn't moved off the front page, though, and can be bumped back onto it.

Consequently, [a negatively voted question is barred from the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62261/are-edited-questions-no-longer-bumped-to-the-front-page/62262#62262), so we already have a non-closing-based mechanism for removing questions from the front page.

For the purpose of front-page-management, I find that the downvotes are good enough and that we don't need to install yet another voting system separate from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your points are valid, but I think your proposed solution is wrong.  Implementing a separate voting system might alleviate some of the symptoms, but doesn't address the real problem.

What we really need to do is educate users about what question closure really means.  We should be more active in letting people know about the reopen feature, and the criteria that make a question a candidate for reopening.  I know I read closed questions, and I encourage others to do the same.  **I don't buy that SO users won't "even care to offer any more help" for closed questions if they understand the system**; they're here to answer questions, and what is answering questions if not caring and helping?

You're right that bounties aren't the solution here; the contract with bounties is rep for increased exposure, not necessarily rep for good answers.

(I've actually had a related feature request for closed questions brewing in my head for a few months; I haven't quite worked out the right wording and details for it yet.)