# Should the upvote or downvote by a higher-reputation programmer count more than the same by a lower-reputation programmer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indicate How Trustworthy the UpVotes Are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22151/indicate-how-trustworthy-the-upvotes-are)

I think it should.

Comment: related: [Weighted Down-Voting based on Reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54494/weighted-down-voting-based-on-reputation)

Comment: Ouch! Those questions did not show up in the Related Questions list.

Answer (score 4):

You think wrong.

**You do not vote for a person, you vote for a question or answer**

Reputation is not an indication of skill, it's an indication of commitment to the site. Period.

<sub>I know this is a duplicate, I just can't find it right now</sub>

Comment: the two Ralph and I found concerned only up *or* down votes, but not both...