# Downvoter anonymous reply feature

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, feedback, anonymous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting)

I've seen many cases where a person downvotes a question/answer and by the means of comments the author requests reason for the downvote. Many downvoters fear retaliation and refuse to give feedback since feedback is nominal.

How about a feature allowing the latest downvoter to provide feedback under the anonymity cover?

Comment: This has already been discussed - see [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/59303) among other questions.

Comment: With anonymous, I suppose you mean visible only to moderators?

Comment: I refuse to give feedback!

Comment: well said MR. wish I could upvote