# Mandatory comment after downvote

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes

I am not sure if this comment about a suggestion on stackoverflow should be written here, but I do think so.

I would recommend, if this is possible, when downvoting a *question*, to be mandatory for the downvoter, to write the reason why he/she downvoted. I think this should be much more helpful for the OP to understand better what he did wrong, in order to fix it, if he does not want to get more downvotes. Downvoting itself, does not help the OP much, nor the people that might have a similar programming problem.

Please write what do you think guys. I know that most of you will disagree with me, but I find that giving feedback when downvoting is more useful for all of us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) or [must comment while downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110279/must-comment-while-downvoting) (and *many* others).

Comment: @jonsca Firstly, I don't get the I think irony of your comment. Secondly, nice picture of a spiking neuron

Comment: @JohnSmith I think that comment is highlighting a core issue with this idea. People down-vote for all kinds of stupid reasons, including perhaps their mood or the weather.

Comment: Thank you! :) But you see the point, even if you could mandate it, you would guarantee a lot of noise being generated in the process.

Comment: @Stijn Are you serious?

Comment: Down-votes cost the voter 1 point of reputation so if that price is worth it to them then they perform a down-vote

Comment: Maybe there should be an incentive, after down-voting tell the voter that if they leave a comment then they can downvote again

Comment: @user2191572 That is also a duplicate.  Many variations of this feature have been proposed.

Comment: @user2191572 Only on answers.

Comment: @Duncan thanks a lot. Yes, that's one not good reason for someone to downvote someone else, and that's one of the reasons that this think might prevent

Comment: @Servy I figured there is, I just wanted a good chuckle =)

Comment: It is not duplicate guys.! I think that I have done my research better than the people that marked my question as duplicate. The question mentioned above, says to encourage comments on ANSWERS. I say mandatory comments when voting down a QUESTION

Comment: @JohnSmith And the problems with the feature request apply to both, making it an appropriate dup target.  Also, re-reading that question, it seems to be discussing both, not just answers.

Comment: @user2191572 Thanks a lot!!! Yes, I find that really great and helpful! Nothing to lose here. However, as I got from the way people answered me, and the downvotes I got, the community will probably disagree with this as well

Comment: @user2191572 Where your comment gone?

Comment: What if: upon downvoting the voter is given the option to provide an anonymous message that only OP can see. This would support the anonymity of downvoting that we love while being helpful to OP.

Comment: @user2191572 nice!

Comment: I'm going to try my hand at this as a question lol

Comment: haha :) You will probably have one upvote (mine) and some downvotes :)

Comment: I don't downvote much, but if I see a really bad posting then I do it, and I certainly don't want to waste additional time having to explain it on top of it. Downvoting a question is IMO questionable anyway but there are already questions about this either.

Comment: =) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215429/a-resolution-for-the-woes-of-getting-downvoted

Comment: probably even better duplicate: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/165773)

Answer (score 8):

First, we believe in anonymous voting here on Stack Exchange so revealing the voters identity by leaving a comment would go against that.

Now, when you downvote a post it goes without saying that it would be good if you were to leave a comment to explain what is wrong with the post but it should **never** be **mandatory**.

Now something has been implemented where, if you have less than 2000 reputation, when you downvote, you will be encouraged by a little popup to leave a comment explaining why you think the post deserves a downvote.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Comments could be anonymous :) but I think it is for the social good to be required. This could help all of us.

Comment: @JohnSmith Np ! This as already been discussed here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting