# How to handle situation when another community member has a different view?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Yesterday, I get into an interesting conversation which I don't know how should it be handled.

I had a question regarding enabling and disabling a functionality in Laravel Nova, after some hours, I solved it and posted the solution which was working fine.

[Policies](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/authorization.html#policies) were something new for me at that time, so it took time to make it work and until I posted that solution

There were also some people who posted answers suggesting hiding it using CSS. I don't believe CSS should be a solution to do something like that, so I did not upvoted/downvoted/accepted those answers.

Now after several months another user posted again a CSS fix, which I do not believe is correct, but they are not ready to listen nor I am able explain them.

I do not know, that is ended I guess, but I do not think that should be the way it goes in this community.

That answer link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904147/5321614).

Comment: Your question simply asks "is there a better way to do this", for which an answer which uses CSS is perfectly valid. If you wanted to exclude CSS answers, the proper move would have been to specify that you don't want to use CSS in the question. Unfortunately, it may be too late for that, as we do have a policy that question edits shouldn't invalidate existing answers.

Comment: No one forces you to engage when someone commented, so the "problem" in your question doesn't really exist. And someone else having a different opinion isn't a problem either.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I have no problem, if people are posting a CSS answer, some people may find it okay and use it.

Comment: @Tom It is not about forcing and getting forced, just wanted to know your views how you people deal with it. so that I will be able to handle it better.

Comment: For this specific case I would recommend flagging comments under your answer (except the first one) as "no longer needed" and disengaging.

Comment: For differences of opinion on technical stuff like this one just post your preferred solution and explain why you think it's better (or others are worse). If that is true, people will use your solution and will upvote it more than others. Just post your ideas and let the users decide what's more useful and what's less. Don't get into prolonged discussions in comments (unless you want to).

Comment: If the question is well-formed, there will always be an answer which is the most correct technically. You need to poke the domain experts about that - therefore this question should be asked at SO meta instead. Or possibly even the main SO site, if the question "Is CSS the correct solution for this" is narrow enough and not opinion-based.

Comment: It's not the first time your question on SO has come up: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/374 - linking in your answer to an authoritative source improves your answer and may encourage more upvotes; you can also ask at that link if you need more specific help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The longer you use Stack Exchange sites, the more often you will encounter other users who have a different view to you.

My advice is to listen to what they say but, if what they say does not seem right to you, then try to explain why.

Always try to support your point of view using examples, and data, if it is available.

Some people choose to agree to differ, I prefer to present my view, and what I think is astray with their view, and then leave them and me to reflect.  Sometimes I conclude that it is "[much easier to lead a horse to water, than to make it drink](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+can+lead+a+horse+to+water)".  Sometimes they come around to my way of thinking.  Other times I come around to theirs.

If what they say is in a post (question or answer) and *you* think it is not useful, then follow the usage advice of the downvote tooltip, and downvote it. If they improve their post then you always have the option to upvote it instead.

Answer (score 6):

> How to handle situation when another community member has a different view

Whatever you do, you do not want to be [this person](https://xkcd.com/386/):

[image: duty calls]

Handling disagreement and frustration is an immensely important skill. It's very important to know when to disengage and walk away. Sometimes you just need to [let it go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MK7qz13bU).

Also, **it's perfectly fine (and necessary) to downvote posts you believe are not correct and/or useful**. If users are posting answers that you believe are incorrect or misleading, do not be afraid to use your votes before going your way.

Comment: and also maybe leave a comment explaining your downvote if you feel like it, it's good etiquette

Comment: No, commenting on votes is not "good etiquette". It's a bad idea and explicitly discouraged. It's perfectly fine to comment on **the post qualities** if one wants, but no need to reference voting at all. Commenting is always optional and secondary.

Comment: can you link to where it is `explicitly discouraged`?

Comment: for what it's worth, [here's a link to a highly upvoted post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) where explaining downvotes is explicitly encouraged, so I'd really like to hear from someone where else it is explicitly discouraged. I remember seeing the message that appeared when you downvote a post, and I remember leaving comments prompted by it, so I assumed it was good etiquette from that.

Comment: @user1306322 It's linked in the post you mentioned, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/686592

Comment: @user1306322 [The help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) says to comment in order to, "Request clarification" and "Leave constructive criticism" -- and that otherwise ("Criticisms which do not add anything constructive") avoid commenting.

Answer (score 5):

> How to handle situation when another community member has a different view

Accept reality. That happens all the time.

Especially regarding technical issues, it is rather:

- If the answer tries to answer the question, but gets that wrong, it is still an answer. The appropriate reaction is a downvote, and maybe a comment why the answer is incorrect. But chances are that the answer will stay in place. Depending on the number of views the question sees, more downvotes my come in over time.
- If the answer really doesn't answer the question, you can flag it for moderator attention for example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe part of the conflict is that questions and answers use unnecessary personal speech. "How can I", "should I", "you can", "you should". While it is common to talk like that in real life, it makes a problem that should be perfectly technical seem personal.

Take the ego out of the problem, make the question abstract, and it may feel less like a difference if opinion if different answers are given. This site is less about dialogue (unless in chat and comments), but more about impersonal descriptions of problems and solutions. Answerers are not giving their answers to *you*, they given then to *the world*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input :)