# Should we allow OPs to open their own closed post at any reputation and designate a special class to such posts?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen, original-poster, binding-vote

Proposal: an OP at any reputation point can reopen their own post when others have voted to close it based, and the post would enter a sort of quarantine from a given general pool of questions where it's answerable, but noted as being closed from the general pool. It would remain their perpetually, searchable within its own isolated class, but not shown in the broader site search index.

This would be a special class. Substantive matters, like hate speech which already has flags to deal with, would remain unopenable under the same 3000 reputation rules.

If it is your opinion we should not do so, please describe why it would be problematic.

Comment: I see 34 downvotes, but no comments? "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." Really? Then help me understand what the 34 of you (at this time) think isn't researched, clear, or useful. This is something well within the capability of this platform, but it appears - based on votes to date - that this is just an unpopular idea because it "presupposes" that your high-level users might be getting things wrong sometimes when they close questions - and heaven forbid addressing a natural shortcoming in an uncredentialed consensus-based opinion platform.

Comment: I don't think changing it to "Should we" will make any difference, because a lot of users don't think so, if those downvotes are anything to tell by.  I'll update my answer in a minute to give you my thoughts; please be patient.

Comment: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/165773)

Comment: [*On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 12):

#### **UPDATE**

Updating my answer to reflect the current state of the question,

**No, I don’t think we should do that.  Why?**

Right now, the only authors who can close their questions whenever they like are moderators and those in possession of a dupehammer (although that’s only for duplicates).  We trust these users with their power because they have *earned* it, through interacting with and contributing to the site.  If I may make a quote:

> New users have a habit of believing their questions are on-topic for that site, else we wouldn’t have posted them.

Currently, editing the post within a certain amount of time triggers a reopen vote and sends it to the Reopen Votes queue, where more experienced users might be able to make a more objective decision, as they will have been with the site longer and know a bit more about how it works.  Allowing a brand-new-to-the-site OP to cast a binding reopen vote might also start edit wars and necessitate the intervention of a moderator.

That is why I think it’s a bad idea.

---

> Closing posts of others should be contestable

It already is.  That’s what reopen votes are for.  If you believe your question was wrongly closed, vote to reopen and edit your question to explain the reasons why you think so.

> This is a case of a person or people with the permissions to close a question not being knowledgeable in the topic at hand, and/or down votes by those who don't understand the topic at hand leading to the automated closing of a valid and focused question.

I don’t know about that.  Because:

1. When your question was reviewed in the Reopen Votes queue, it was reviewed by 3 additional *human* users who voted to keep your question closed because they believed it needed more focus *according to the site guidelines*; it was not “automatically closed”,
2. A few of the users who closed your question have a good chunk of reputation (10K, 70K etc.), which might indicate that they contribute well to that site and may actually understand the topic at hand very well, contrary to your accusation,
3. Questions don’t get closed from downvotes.  You can cast downvotes without fear of them resulting in a closure.

Answer (score 5):

I guess there's a fairly critical reason this would fail - to put it bluntly, it pre-supposes that OP somehow magically figured out on their own what was wrong with the question. Our current approach, of an automatic reopen vote on the first edit, has the effect of throwing the post into the review queue for more experienced users to take a look.

And putting the question in a "a sort of quarantine" doesn't do something a review queue does not.  The time to answer is *after* the question has approached something *close* to its final form, and said state is something that fits our standard.

Ironically - I actually do think there's a few points in previous revisions worth addressing,

> I'm suggesting we remove the reputation limit governing the ability to vote to reopen your own post.

Reputation acts as both a sign that you have knowledge of a subject and of the ways of the network. A premature reopening may mean a *reclosure*, which does no one any good.

You also talk about a 'specifications' site - We actually experimented with hardware and software recommendation sites on the network. They work to an extent, but I wouldn't consider them a roaring suspect. As a ex-Software recs mod - the main reason it works is *very* careful curation, lots of criteria for a good answer and the overlap in expertise.

For a "DIY recommendations" site to work, you would need someone who either works with, or geeks out over such devices *on the site* - water heaters are something people generally hardly think about to take your example, and do extensive research. We just replace ours with the same brand/equal model every decade or so.

For Hardware and software recs, as a tech based network, and with relatively narrow scopes our audiences have a good crossover. DIY's much more broad based.

Comment: How would one get that started then? ... DIY recommendations ... that sounds fantastic. Same issue as any DIY post/comment/answer... it's a consensus based voting system that doesn't require any formal knowledge to vote, just a certain level of "reputation points". ... more broadly "meta" I'm going to keep bringing up the fact that if people don't acknowledge that someone with 166k reputation, #1 on a site, doesn't mean they're capable of being dead wrong, then this site is not about the primacy of rules and guidelines and new users are equal, it's just a popularity club.