# Should moderators have the right to vote on questions?

Tags: feature-request, voting, moderators

I have come across of what is in my opinion of moderators in PSE bias by downvoting specific questions systematically even if these are backed up by the literature.

Negative votes are cast even a few minutes after the question is published prior of any votes by the readers normal users. This is done even without leaving any comment for the downvote and leave the users asking mesmerized of what is wrong with the question?

I believe this to be a general phenomenon in SE forums.

Unless a moderator actively participates on a question by answering or asking his/her own question, why a moderator should have the right of voting promoting or not in general questions?

Let the normal users decide for that if a question is interesting and or valid scientific and is to be up voted or down voted? And not instead just straight a few minutes after the question is asked, biasing the mood by the moderator.

Of course moderators will retain the right to tag the question any time they decide, put it as off-topic, duplicate etc.

IMO a moderator must be neutral.

Comment: How do you know who is casting votes if they aren't commenting?

Comment: I don't but this makes SE users suspicious and discouraged participating in SE forums even more regular visiting users. So I propose to scratch out this possibility and root out any possible bias.

Comment: As a note, "Moderator" is a term here used to refer to elected moderators, of which each site has only a handful (with a few exceptions) most moderators are not likely the people you're talking about. You only need 125 reputation to downvote - which is a far cry from elected moderator status.

Comment: Still. I believe a moderator must be neutral.

Comment: The moderators generally are. I've spent time getting to know many of them. Their focus, as is the focus of so many people on the platform, is in helping to guide the community as the community requests - so the people who curate our sites work hard to identify content that does not fit into the expectations for being on topic and clear and often recommend improvements to those posts. Downvoting is intended to be a signal that something is wrong with the post. Please understand that "being neutral" can not mean "allows content that doesn't fit the site's scope or quality expectations".

Comment: I completely understand that having nothing explaining why a post is being downvoted is frustrating and I don't want to invalidate that - I feel it often when I'm in the same situation - but that doesn't mean that the downvote is somehow "wrong" or not "neutral". It becomes my job as a post author to reexamine my post and ask myself what might be wrong with it that I'm missing. And... sometimes there's nothing I can find, but sometimes I find better ways to word my answer or question and that helps others understand what I mean.

Comment: Well, you can always tag a question as off-topic etc. for that. I don't see how moderators voting has any merits in moderating SE forums and is a tactic prone to bias. So I propose it as a bias prevention measure. No one doubts the tremendous effort and admirable contribution of the moderators in the SE forums but humans can have momentary a loss of good judgement. So there is no reason to involve moderators with this.

Comment: Seems to be a reaction to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/681111/would-a-change-of-the-spacetime-topology-inside-a-black-hole-be-a-possible-consi) which perhaps has some deleted comments. In any case your problems with that question and the reaction to it are probably better raised on [Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Comment: I strongly disagree with barring some of the most prolific users of the sites from using those sites, especially users who are expected beyond the norm to understand the nuances of the sites they moderate.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes that is correct I have previously re-edited the question topic more than 4 times and asked as suggested a new related question and it is always a few minutes later downvoted or closed. I'm frustrated. I can't spend a whole 2 hours of my time trying to ask a question! I did not know however about the PSE meta. So sorry about that.

Comment: @RobertLongson "...which perhaps has some deleted comments.". No comments by others nor deleted comments.

Comment: "Negative votes are cast even a few minutes after the question is published prior of any votes by the readers normal users." - You have absolutely no proof that is the case. You have provided zero proof that the user(s) who are downvoting your contributions are actually elected moderators. At the end of the day, moderators are members of the community, hence the reason they are consider to be "community moderators".  Often they have extensive knowledge in some area within the scope of the Stack Exchange community they are a moderator of. **SE community websites are not a discussion forum**

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate @Rob.  Any user with the downvote privilege can downvote any post (except their own) they think to not be useful.  A moderator downvoting is not exercising a moderator privilege; they are using a user privilege.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: *IMO a moderator must be neutral.* It is literally the moderators' job to make judgements about content on the site (whether something is rude, spam, needs deletion, etc.). Asking them to be neutral doesn't make sense.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?).

Comment: It is not necessarily formal moderators, but yes, this is a problem on the smaller Stack Exchange sites where a small group of users keep newcomers and others out by downvoting or *never* upvoting. They only upvote within that small group, effectively forming a voting cabal (even though it is not directly coordinated, the effect is the same).

Answer (score 14):

A moderator downvoting a question, given what *other* powers they have, is probably the most merciful action they can take on a question.

They're also some of the most experienced users on the site, so taking away their ability to vote is hugely detrimental.

Comment: For newer folks who are unfamiliar with abilities that moderators have, see the [Help Center page about site moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) for a breakdown of what they can do/see above and beyond voting.

Answer (score 10):

Elected moderators are usually amongst the most experienced users of the sites they moderate, often curating Stack Exchange site content for several to many years before becoming moderators.

Consequently, I think they should retain their user privilege to downvote content that they think is not useful.

If you think the same content is useful, then (unless it is your own post, or you have not yet obtained the [upvote privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)) I think you should upvote it.  Your upvote carries five times the weight of a downvote (irrespective of whether it comes from a moderator or any other user) so you are well placed to influence what your community deems to be useful content.

Answer (score -11):

Well, you can always tag a question as off-topic etc. for that. I don't see how moderators voting has any merits in moderating SE forums and is a tactic prone to bias. So I propose it as a bias prevention measure. No one doubts the tremendous effort and admirable contribution of the moderators in the SE forums but humans can have momentary a loss of good judgement. So there is no reason to involve moderators with this.

Also, I proposed in my question that moderators of course can vote if they answer a question or in their own question.

I can see that this proposal hit a nerve but I sincerely believe that it would be for bettering SE.

Comment: By "tag a question as off-topic" I think you mean vote to close as off-topic.  By "SE forums" I think you mean SE sites, which are Q&A sites, [not forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/215590).