# Why can't we object to a downvote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes

I saw this as a closed question, and maybe I am wrong for starting it up again, but there should be a method for *objecting to a downvote*.

Please keep in mind, some of us are not the best with "words." Yes, I should try to do better when asking questions. But at the same time I have been very tolerant to what I consider people who just want to downvote, or troll. "Why would you want to do that?" is not an acceptable answer, or a reason to downvote my question.

But there's a difference between someone who isn't articulate, and someone who just wants other people to do their homework for them.

Again, am not the most articulate person, here and in person. But I am just trying to find a way to get help with blocks I run across.

If I continue to try and improve myself, but to just get downvotes with no explanations, and no way to object, then I'm just being denied access to help that I genuinely need.

Comment: It isn't possible to vote on your own content. It is therefore not possible to object/counter a vote on a post that is yours. The owner of a post claiming their post shouldn't be downvoted is clearly a biased opinion, you wouldn't post something you felt shouldn't be posted.

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. Do you have any particular methods to suggest "... for *objecting to a down vote*", including how they would work & what possible results may be?

Comment: You could always post a comment to you post to object to the down vote. Votes are anonymous, and requiring an explanation will break that. Some people are not comfortable revealing themselves due to retaliation. Others may comment about the problem, or may respond to your comment with constructive criticism.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: Post a comment under your downvoted post, calmly asking what you can improve about it. *"I'm just being denied access to help"* This sounds like you think that people who downvote your questions are not the same people who would answer them. But the two groups heavily overlap.

Comment: “… I consider people who just want to down vote, or troll.” - We have also been tolerate, of you asking questions, that could be clearer. A downvote is one of only a few options to conveying that message. Users who issue a downvote are not enjoying doing that, most understand the ramifications, of a downvote especially if that user might or might not have a pattern of asking questions that are not well received.  So before you take a downvote as an act of trolling, you must understand, asking a question that could be better and isn’t improved isn’t entirely positive either.

Answer (score 10):

The hover text for a downvote illustrates the general rationale as to why someone decided to downvote your question.

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

In *general* that's the reason that someone downvotes your question (or answer).  Asking why would encourage a lot more discussion about the quality of your question as opposed to the question you want to answer, so I'd recommend not asking.

There is a misconception hidden here, though.

> But at the same time I have been very tolerant to what I consider people who just want to down vote, or troll. "Why would you want to do that?" is not an acceptable answer, or a reason to down vote my question.

You think people that downvote are trolling you?  It's really not *about* you specifically, it's about the question.  They are not attacking *you*; don't take the votes personally.

They sting and I get that, but they serve as the only reasonable tool the rest of the community has (without becoming your personal pin cushion) to inform you that your question isn't quite to standards.

---

Not that I'm in the business of making myself a pin cushion, but I chose to downvote this feature request as a means to disagree with it.  Contesting downvotes means that we get further and further away from the goal of Q&A.  This is nothing to do with you - I've never seen you until literally this instant.  It's just that I don't believe your suggestion is viable for the site.