# Is it a bug? Deleted question was undeleted by another user

Tags: bug, edits, questions, deleted-questions

I asked a question on Stack Overflow and deleted it because I found the answer myself. At the same time, someone had already posted an answer. This is of course unfortunate but I wanted to delete the question anyway.

I successfully deleted my question. The user edited my question 20 minutes later and thus reactivated it.

Is this a bug?

Comment: What do you mean by "reactivated"? Is the question undeleted now?

Comment: I assume you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691678/how-do-i-get-a-webpack-bundled-files-to-run, it was undeleted by a moderator.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes is undeleted now and i cant delete anymore because the use got after undeleted an upvote.

Comment: "*and deleted it because I found the answer myself.*" why would you need to delete the question in that case? The point of a question is to leave lasting value for future visitors. If you had found the answer, you could have posted it.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine Yes of course! I mean this issue! Thank you!

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I see it the same way as you do. But I didn't want to accept the neagtive repuation because it wasn't commented on. Downvotes are fine if you comment on them. but downvoting and moving on is bad in my opinion.

Comment: Best [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An edit never undeletes a question automatically. A user, who has more than 10k rep, could see your question and edit it, but certainly not undelete it via a binding vote.

As we can see in [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71691678/timeline), a user has answered your question. Then you deleted it and a moderator undeleted it (probably because you deleted it after it was answered).

[image]

Comment: Ok. Thank you for answer.  Ok. Then I understand correctly that it is not a bug? Then it's my fault.

Comment: @maik not a bug :)