# Need help understanding what is the official response to some feature requests

Tags: discussion

Since my earlier [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237859/incentivizing-people-to-leave-a-comment-with-downvote-by-1-assigning-different) has been marked as a possible duplicate, I would like to find out what was the final resolutions to these?:

1. [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)
2. [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting?rq=1)

Just looking at the number of upvotes cast for the questions, it appears that the features requested are what users would like to see added. 537 upvotes and 51 upvotes respectively.

I was wondering who *'officially'* responded, what was the response, and the reasons for the response?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/226203) was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/135/5) revision, by Jeff Atwood, around July '09. A quick look at the accepted answer on that question shows it was posted, by Jeff, around that same time. Thus, the accepted answer can be taken as the official position.

The [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6521/226203) there was similarly [marked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/6521/4) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) [by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/6521/4) around August 2011. He didn't post an answer, so the official position is mostly just "No.", though SE employees have explained in several places that anonymous commenting of any sort is basically a non-starter, due to potential abuse.

Comment: Thank you! _though SE employees have explained in several places that anonymous commenting of any sort is basically a non-starter, due to potential abuse._ No evidence provided? If an anonymous comment can lead to abuse, why can't an anonymous vote? It appears that the feeling users asking for feature-request are getting.

Comment: Anonymous downvotes are a crucial part of allowing people to freely downvote content they don't like, which helps to separate the good and bad content of the site, without fear of retribution. Anonymous comments, on the other hand, would quickly devolve into rather petty crap; comments are a second-class feature anyway, so encouraging more isn't really desirable. And tying downvotes to anonymous comments, as in that second question, would lead to the anonymous comments literally only being posted on crap, meaning even lower quality.

Comment: Talking about downvote with no comments. Not anonymous comments on their own. What is wrong with linking anonymous comment and the anonymous vote? i.e. no comment no downvote? or less strict, no comment, less of a downvote, and comment more value for the negative downvote?

Comment: @FMShyanguya Your last comment refers to a request that has been talked about here pretty much literally to death.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thank you again. You come across as a good person so thank you for not _feeling burdened again_ by another yet again on  the same request. *a request that has been talked about here pretty much literally to death* this is my problem though, a system that works well shouldn't generate requests like this and cause this kind of reaction. It appears to me a case of unreasonable intransigence on the part of the powers that be.

Comment: @FMShyanguya I can appreciate that feeling, but there are a great many reasons for this that it seems only experience can reveal. Keep in mind, also, that each time this is brought up, the overwhelming response is "**no**".

Comment: @AndrewBarber for upvotes on the links, it is 537 and counting and 51 and counting respectively not counting answers in favor.. The overwhelming **'no'** is from whom?

Comment: @fmshyanguya 537 on encouraging. That's been done. Neither does the second require comments on votes. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Splitting hairs I believe.

Comment: @fms not splitting hairs in the least. Encouraging is much different than requiring.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I stand corrected. But please note both are saying with comments is preferred than without.

Comment: @FMShyanguya And the official position is that they would prefer people to comment along with their downvotes, but are under no obligation to do so as voting is *intended* to be anonymous. The community at large doesn't dispute that comments are preferred along with a downvote, but **strongly** disagrees that they should be required.

Comment: @JonK An impasse isn't it? It is a good thing and it is wanted, but we can't figure out how to effect it.

Comment: @FMShyanguya No, it isn't a good thing, and I daresay it's only wanted by people that haven't considered the full ramifications of requiring comments to go along with downvotes. Not only would there be an increase in revenge and serial downvoting, but quite frankly I *don't want* to have to comment on the metric ton of **crap** that comes through on Stack Overflow *every day*. It would be a largely futile exercise in trying to educate people who have no interest in the Stack Exchange community at large and who are simply here for their one-off quick fix, never to be seen again.

Comment: @JonK Thank you for the engagement. I must now accept things will be like this, to the revulsion of my logic.