# Is there a way to request an user to explain his/her vote?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I just would like to know the reason why a question I formulated was down voted.

Comment: The down vote button tooltip has info: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*

Comment: see: [What is a recommendation question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Comment: @rene I saw that one but my question was more in the sense if I could somehow "request" an user to explain the vote (with some kind of messaging)

Comment: No, that will never happen or otherwise users will stop down voting

Comment: @rene more likely those people who used to downvote will stop using Stack Exchange, and thus SE will become a pale copy of Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: @rene It could be done anonymously, for example. In the sense that the requester wouldn't know who is the one receiving the request

Comment: Do you really think that hasn't been proposed before? Read [the checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), that might be helpful.

Comment: @rene thanks for the list, I'll check

Comment: You should instead ask why users upvote posts in the first place

Comment: [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6521/165773)

Comment: The most you can do is leave a non-confrontational comment on your question, like "HEY ASSHO... no, I mean, "I'm glad to fix any issues with my question if you could do me the favor of letting me know about them!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such way.

People are free to downvote as they see fit, without the need to explain. This is a core feature of Stack Exchange, that is probably not going to change, despite numerous requests to change it.

Worth to mention that asking in a comment "Why the downvotes?" usually only results in more downvotes, so it's not a good idea.

Answer (score -6):

Nope!

Comment: Personally I ignore downvotes if there's just one, as long as the question itself is still positive (ie, more upvotes than downvotes).  If you want us to evaluate your question and give you suggestions as to what might cause someone to downvote, post a link and we can offer some insight.

Comment: It was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022109/how-to-preview-html-and-css-on-netbeans Thanks Adam!

Comment: @Javier Your question is about getting a feature on Netbeans to work, or finding another plugin for Netbeans.  It's not a programming question, it appears to be a netbeans support question, or webmaster question.  Stack Overflow is very focused on programming questions that can be answered with code, not plugins. I hesitate to recommend it because I'm not a strong member of their community, but you might be able to find help at the webmasters Stack Exchange - [read their help FAQs first to find out if your question is a good fit](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I downvoted this because of irony.