# Can anyone give a negative rating on a question because he just judges so?

Tags: support, questions, down-votes

I have asked the following question in Stack Overflow:
"Why is padding of action buttons ignored in the device?"
I followed it with a specific code example. 
I received a negative rating on the same day w/o even an accompanying comment so that I know where the problem is. I even ask the person to write a comment since I really can't see what makes this question bad  but I got no reply. So, most probably the person is not OK. Yet, he/she has the right to "blindly" rate a question negatively. Is this acceptable? Can anyone do this because he/she just judges so?
Now, this negative rating reduces the chances for my question to be answered!

Comment: We're just talking about a single downvote here. I wouldn't sweat it to much. Take a step back and see how you can improve it. And why the multiple accounts?

Comment: I often try to blindly downvote questions, but I have a hard time hitting the button with my eyes closed.

Comment: @Won't You, sir, you I like. :)

Comment: We are encourage to issue votes.  It is suggested we leave constructive comments when we leave a vote but it is not required.  In other words, we can issue a vote, for any reason except if its targeted towards a specific user.

Comment: You didn't see the quotation marks around "blindly".  So I guess you can miss hitting buttons even with your eyes open.

Answer (score 12):

> Is this acceptable? Can anyone do this because he/she just judges so?

Yes. That's how the system works. We don't *know* why someone downvoted a post. But - it usually means something isn't right with it (in particular if there are *several* such votes).

Instead of getting upset about it, take it as a helpful hint - a reason to look at the post and figure out if you can make it better.

Answer (score 2):

A point you made in your question

> I even ask the person to write a comment since I really can't see what makes this question bad but I got no reply.

[A comment is not required for a downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6524/245360) - thinking about it, there would not really be any way to enforce commenting, specifically due to voting being (rightfully) anonymous.

It certainly does not mean it is an attack on you, or on the topic of your question per se, but rather something missing from the question - reread the hints provided in the tour and help pages.