# What's your up/down vote ratio?

Tags: discussion, voting, polling

I'm just curious: What's your up/down vote ratio? I'm still new here, but so far my ratio is about 11 to 1 with 209 up-votes and 19 down-votes.

I suspect that members become more bitter with time, and start downvoting more. Are there some statistics that can confirm this?

Answer (score 6):

- SuperUser - 28.333(repeating) with a current rep of just over 1,000
- ServerFault - 8 with a current rep of 319
- StackOverflow - 8.7362637362637362637362637362637 with a current rep of almost 13,000
- Meta - 19.55 with a current rep almost to 5,000

I think once people hit the 3,000 mark and then the 10,000 mark you will start to see rather drastic changes in their voting patterns which would allow for more down votes. I know that was the case with me. Once I hit 10k I stopped caring much about my rep in StackOverflow and was much more willing to cast downvotes on things since I no longer felt like I needed to keep getting a higher and higher score.

I should also note that the longer you are a member, the higher your ratios are going to be (it will almost never shrink) because it is almost insane to imagine someone not named Rich B casting more downvotes per day than upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's some generalized statistics](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=SELECT%20Round((UpVotes/DownVotes),%200)%20AS%20Ratio,%20Count(*)%20as%20Occurances%20FROM%20users%20WHERE%20DownVotes%20!=%200%20GROUP%20BY%20Ratio%20ORDER%20BY%20Occurances%20DESC%20LIMIT%2050).

It should be noted that **82000 people have never downvoted**, and there is only just under 94000 users.

Comment: Most of those probably do not have the privilege to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

**SO:**   599 to 43 
*approximately a 9 up to 1 down on average*
**SU:**   57 to 3 
*approximately a 10 up to 1 down on average*
**SF:**   7 to 1 
*precisely a a 7 up to 1 down on average*
**META:** 206 to 44 
*approximately 4 up to 1 down on average*

**FAMILY:** 869 to 91 
*approximately a 9 up to 1 down on average*

Some Highlights...  I'm probably **WAY TOO NICE!**  I would be at over 2K points here on META if I did not vote down 43 times though...  I also think that I'm more likely to vote down on META because the rep doesn't mean as much to me here as stackoverflow itself at this time.

Comment: oh no... tactical down voting... what should I do?  shut-up and ignore it...

Comment: I didn't 'tactically' vote on you. I voted for Bill who is above me, for instance. I just don't see how what you posted is any different from what TheTXI, Damien, Manni, etc posted to the point where yours was somehow more valuable. If I didn't post at all I can assure you I would have voted the same.

Comment: @Ian: If that was your logic, I take it that you voted down the others as well?

Comment: No, only yours. I didn't say it didn't deserve credit, I just don't feel it deserved *more* credit then other identical responses.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't think people down vote enough, I see way to many answers that are just plain wrong or mis-informed that don't get down voted and leave bad advice or suggestions that someone that is new won't know is bad advice or suggestion. And there will be people with 10K or more reputation that post answers and still don't down vote the empirically bad answers.

I up vote the answers that are most importantly correct, and then well thought out and detailed. But I feel I am the only critic some times down voting all the wrong answers that don't even address the question at hand because someone answered without reading for comprehension. C# answers on Java questions, and vice versa are good examples.

**What does meta think?**

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), it's pretty easy to obtain some more up-to-date sitewide figures.

[This simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66779/vote-stats) lists how many votes of each type were cast.

Answer (score 0):

I'm shocked! That would be 3.39 for me on so. I'm a negative bastard!

Comment: You would be in good company: Jeff Atwood is ~4 :)  And the record low, Rich B, is around 0.5!!!

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow: 331 Up votes to 7 Downvotes

So around 47 to 1

Answer (score 0):

On StackOverflow:

> 1201:94

12.777

I'm a nice guy.

Comment: 1734:27 = 64.222. I'm a nicer guy. :P

Comment: Wow, that is a huge ratio.  I commend your niceness.

Answer (score 0):

I knew I was generous with up-votes, but didn't think I was that stingy with down-votes.

SF: 521-1
SO: 129-0
SU: 122-0
Meta: 74-0

plus a handful flagged for spam and moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

12.88 for me on Stackoverflow. That puts me in the realm of the "nice," right?

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow: 9.4:1

Answer (score 0):

SO: 156-1

SU: 20-0

Answer (score 0):

I've been more or less active on SO since public beta started in September, and I currently have 17.8k rep. I don't *think* I've become bitter with age; my upvote-to-downvote ratio is 1742:27 = 64.52.

I've explained my reasoning for downvotes [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers/2455#2455); basically, I downvote only in extreme circumstances.

I upvote whenever I like an answer or question, which happens quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337/brad-gilbert)

  - rep: 3109
  - `^  1418`
  - `v 37`
  - `1418:37 == 38.3:1`
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users/768/brad-gilbert)

  - rep: 562
  - `^ 269`
  - `v 2`
  - `269:2 == 134.5:1`
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/1508/brad-gilbert)

  - rep: 312
  - `^ 84`
  - `v 0`
  - `84:0 == ∞:1`
- [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1337/brad-gilbert)

  - rep: 1060
  - `^ 383`
  - `v 1`
  - `383:1 == 383:1`

Answer (score 0):

10 to 1.
But I guess the individual ratio is not as important as the global ratio which shows the level of quality of the questions not individual aggressiveness.

Answer (score 0):

SO: 369 up,  26 down

MetaSO: 9 up

SU: 9 up, 1 down

SF: none

I never took myself to be such a positive guy!   I guess I just only downvote when I think an answer is really bad advice.