# c# is clearly dominant on SO. Is there a desire, need or whatever to diversify the user base and questions?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, statistics, data-analysis, languages

*(UPDATE: Anybody who thinks this is a rant on C# needs to chill out.  I'm not suggesting punishing C# questions.  Rather, I am* envious *of C#'s disproportionate popularity on SO and am asking what, if anything, can or should be done to get non-C# language communities to more interested in using SO as they place for Q&Ss.  Why?  SO rocks as a Q&A platform, much more that traditional forums.)*

On a whim, I thought it would be entertaining to graph out the *Top Ten Language* Question Tags by Date*.  It has always been clear that c# was the most popular tag, but the below graphs made this fact more of a reality is some way.  It kind of bothers me, but then again it is such a multifaceted topic that my 20-second analysis of why this is so doesn't mean much to even myself.

**What are your thoughts on the overwhelmingly large popularity of c# on Stack Overflow?**  Is this healthy?  Normal?  In need of a conscious, deliberate change?

(* = My own arguably arbitrary and biased selection based on the most popular tags)

**Top Ten Language Question Tags (+ 'r') by Date:**
[Stack Overflow: Top Ten Programming Languages Over Time http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/Stack-Overflow-Top-Ten-Languages-Over-Time-small.png](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/Stack-Overflow-Top-Ten-Languages-Over-Time-small.png)

([3.3MB full size image](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/Stack-Overflow-Top-Ten-Languages-Over-Time.png))

Also included in the graph is `r`, which users of `r` flash-posted questions about in July.  Here is a zoom of their "flash".  It's kinda cute, in a way.  They managed to

- beat out `c` and `ruby-on-rails` for a day
- approach the lulls in activity in a couple of popular tags, like `asp.net` and `java`

[link text http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/Stack-Overflow-Top-Ten-Languages-Over-Time-Zoom.png](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/Stack-Overflow-Top-Ten-Languages-Over-Time-Zoom.png)

Comment: It's an awesome language :)

Comment: @Mehrdad Maybe its, or maybe the only true awesome language it the one who does not raise any questions as an indication of its easy of use and power. ( Although the there is a really thin line between: This programming language is so easy/powerful that nobody has something to ask and: This so lame nobody uses it at all ) mmhhh :-/

Comment: What exactly are we seeing on the Y axis?  Is that number of unanswered questions?  Number of questions posted per time period?

Comment: Graph title: *"... Language Question Tags ... by Date"*, so the number of questions with that tag for each day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compared that analysis to stats about language usage/popularity, you would be able to determine what languages were over/under represented on SO. The question them becomes how to better "get the word out" about SO to users of those languages.

Comment: Well, yea.  But that would only come after answering the *"do we/SO/Jeff need to?"* question.  So far, folks seem hostile towards the idea that there is even a need.  Hump.

Answer (score 17):

It's healthy, and normal.  It doesn't need a deliberate change.  I don't see how you'd accomplish that anyway.  My favorite language (Perl) is a minority (not even on your graph, I see) and yet it's still possible to get insightful and intelligent answers to Perl questions.  So I don't think any problem exists.

Comment: **`Perl++`**  ​

Comment: I'm expecting "Please add {insert my language of choice} to the graph"...if there are lots of a particular language, I'll do so :)

Comment: I don't think you need to add Perl to the graph, there are only ~2k **`[perl]`** questions

Comment: It does not seem to have been communicated well, but I am not suggesting that we change SO directly, in the code base.  (Or c# coders are super sensitive and territorial :P but I don't think so.) J&J have done a bang up job of using their existing community base to market SO, but it seems to be very c# heavy to me.  Why are other communities so SO-shy, can we encourage formally encourage interest outside the c# community, and should we?

Answer (score 6):

Here is another graph for the discussion.  I wanted to bring in some outside data in an attempt to make this a more objective conversation.   As a measure of how other languages are rank against each other in SO and the outside world, I grabbed data from the top 10 languages on the [TIOBE Programming Community Index for September 2009](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) and graphed it against the corrosponding Stack Overflow question tag counts.

- *x*-axis: ***"Popularity on Stack Overflow"***, measured as percent of composite for SO question tags
- *y*-axis: ***"Popularity on TOIBE Index"***, measured as a percent of the composite of the top ten languages in the TOIBE index
- *z*-axis: ***"Consensus Popularity"***, the bubble size, is measured by multiplying SO % value and TOIBE % value

*Note:* VB was kind of hard to do because on TOIBE it is "(Visual) BASIC" and SO there are many tags with VB, and I restricted it to VB + VB.NET.

What does this say to me?  ***"Stack Overflow questions most definitely over represent C#, relative to other languages."***  Other than Rob Allen's answer, almost every other answer and comment here on this point sounds like a subjective justification of the *status quo*.

*(Stu hunkers down for the inevitable blow back from overly sensitive C# fans who think he is a C# hater.)*

[alt text http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/stackoverflow-langue-popularity-versus-TOIBE.png](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/images/stackoverflow-langue-popularity-versus-TOIBE.png)

Comment: You some kind of C♭ lover?

Comment: So Jon Skeet's code is actually slightly _under_ represented on StackOverflow? Good god, he's a monster!

Answer (score 4):

There is a potential issue of [construct validity](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/constval.php) here. The number of C# tags may indeed be higher but there are a number of possible explanations for that besides "language popularity." There may be more confussion surrounding C# than other languages for example. There may also be more ways to describe a problem in C# and therefore more overlap and duplication between questions.

If we assume that it *is* because C# is just more popular, I would have to agree with @Jon B's assessment that its a matter of getting the word out to other programming communities. But I really think that it is way too early in the life of SO to worry about that. They have built it, more will come.

Comment: Hmmmm...interesting.  I'm not that familiar with the `.net` world, so it is all a bit exotic to me.

Answer (score 4):

There are 275k post of which 36k are tagged `c#`. Big deal.

It doesn't prevent people from getting good answers in dozens of other tags. I mean, come'on, there is an active (if small) LaTeX community here.

I don't see this as a problem.

Comment: Not all 275k questions are language specific, are they.

Comment: No, of course not. So look at it this way: 18k java, 13k javascript, 13k c++, 9k python, 8k sql, 5k ruby-on-rails, 4k objective-c and already we have more than twice as many tagged with *other* languages than tagged c# and I haven't gotten to the 30th most popular tag yet. c# has a plurality, but not a majority.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with people asking questions in C#?  I see nothing wrong with it they need help and Stack overflow gives it to them.

Is it healthy?  Yes, Stack overflow is a place for people to get help in programming, regardless of language. There is help for everybody which is the goal of stack overflow.

Yes it is completely normal, there are a large number of people writing C# code everyday and they need help.

No change is needed, Stack overflow doesn't have rules that state you are only allowed to ask C# questions, and we should not prevent them either.

Comment: *"Healthy"*, would be in the context of folks considering SO to be a c#/.net domain unwelcoming or interested in others.  I've not  suggested changing SO to discourage c# question.  (Your last sentence is just plain silly, hyperbolic cwap.)  Rather, I am suggesting that *maybe* we need to get other communities more interested in SO as a platform for asking/answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a desire to diversity the user base. If we want StackOverflow to be THE source of questions and answers for programming, that only makes sense.

To assume that we have a **problem** because the majority of the users are .NET/C#'ers is incorrect thinking. It is natural for those who follow Jeff & Joel (mostly .NET C#'ers) to be the starting audience, and we have seen the audience constantly grow since. It should not be seen as a bad thing that we happen to have a very large "seed" community centered around a particular language.

It's not like there is any shunning of particular languages and technologies going on. If you don't care for a language, you don't have to contribute and someone else will pick up your slack.

Comment: The problem I am asking if we have is not the abundance of c# questions, but the *relative* drought of questions for other languages.  Think of all those poor COBOL programmers, maintaining the world's most popular language, still writing letters to each other to exchange Q&As!  They could benefit from what I think is a superior way to address programming Q&A communications.

Comment: @Stu those poor COBOL programmers are not looking at stackoverflow and thinking "if only it wasn't so tilted toward c#, I could use it...". If they need help, they will search for it, and they will find SO.

Comment: @Rex: No, they won't, if there is no useful info to them on stackoverflow.

Comment: The problem is that the "someone else" who's going to "pick up your slack" might not be on SO at all.

Answer (score 1):

SO is actually working, I have the C# tag in my ignore list so I did not even noticed that C# was growing...

If you want more languages on SO, then market the ignore tag (with the hide option enabled) and this will not be a problem at all!

Comment: Huh?  Marking the ignore tag will not address the 'problem' that I am suggesting/asking.  E.g.: There are only 68 COBOL questions and no amount of tag hiding is going to change that fact, other than the COBOL community paying more attention to SO.  COBAL *is* after all the world's most popular language! </sarcasm>

Comment: If a Cobol expert comes along, he probably will be put down by the number of C# questions and go to another place... but if he knows that he can "ignore" that noise then maybe SO can help him find what he wants...

Comment: If that were the case, they'd never be around long enough to figure out your beloved ignore list feature, would they? Marketing of a niche feature or not.  Sorry, just not buying your answer.

Comment: @Johan - Just checked the list of top voted Cobol questions. They are entry-level, like "how do I learn Cobol". Comper the top-voted C# questions, for instance "hidden features of C#", "common programming mistakes in C#", "useful attributes". If Cobol experts are online, they aren't on StackOverflow. You need to attract them somehow, and I don't think a nice UI is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bit of a problem. IMHO Stack Overflow depended on two things to get started: a nice web UI and a critical mass of expert developers. Joel and Jeff supplied the critical mass through their blog audiences: mostly Windows/.NET developers. I don't think we can count on this automatically spreading to all other technologies because you need a critical mass to get started. Otherwise, it goes like this.

1. Fred stumbles on Stack Overflow.
2. Fred posts a question about SilverBulletTech (TM)
3. No good answers, because no-one knows SilverBulletTech (TM).
4. Fred goes back to the SilverBulletTech (TM) Usenet group, where the UI is poor but at least someone helps you.

**EDIT**: IMHO an example is C - there are [complaints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers/2457#2457) that the quality of C answers on StackOverflow is [not very high](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers/2457#2457). If that's true, we can't expect to attract C developers. C# developers are attracted to StackOverflow partly by the UI, but mainly by answers by a big community including world-class experts like Jon Skeet and Eric Lippert.

We need to get a marketing whizzkid (or [business wonk](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/)) on the case. Hmm, maybe they already are. I expect "building the brand" is one of the motives behind the developer days.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it would be desirable to include everybody, but I think this is going to happen through word of mouth.  People will find out that SO is a good place for some answers, and will tend to join, and provide answers for even more subjects.

The big question is barriers to entry, and I haven't seen them.  Nobody is systematically downvoting Java questions and answers that I've noticed, and nobody seems to be systematically leaving nasty comments.