# What are the criteria to down-vote an answer?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do you cast downvotes on answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers)

What are the criteria to down-vote an answer?
Should an answer be down-voted only if it is not correct, or there are other criteria too?

Comment: It says "This answer is not useful" on the tooltip.

Comment: Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers

Comment: There are rules? I always downvoted whenever I felt like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I see it:

- It does not provide any useful information
- It does not answer this particular question but something else
- It contains wrong information that could lead to misunderstanding of some concept

You should absolutely take a neutral point and never downvote an answer if you personally dislike the author or if the answer addresses some annoying issue that irritates you but still (unfortunately) happens to be true. As they say, don't kill the messenger.