# Is the reputation given for accepting an answer removed, when the account of the answer deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, deleted-accounts

I have noticed that for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33422/140449), the reputation shows me this.

[image: screenshot]

Does that mean the reputation given from accepting an answer is removed when the account used to answer is deleted?

I tried unselecting that answer, and accepting it again. The reputation shows me this.

[image: screenshot]

The answer is accepted from me.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think those events on Jul 11<sup>th</sup> 2010 have anything to do with the user deletion. That user wasn't deleted until at least [May 7<sup>th</sup> 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/what-exactly-happens-when-i-ask-to-delete-my-account).

From the post's [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/33418/timeline), I'm inclined to say that you simply accepted and unaccepted that answer multiple times. Your rep history on the dates you accepted or unaccepted that answer seems consistent.

IOW, no I don't think user deletion does anything to the accept rep. You're still at +2 from that accept.