# Abuse of the voting system to obtain electorate badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting, electorate-badge

I see the electorate badge is given to people who cast 600+ votes and 25% have to be on questions. Do you think people are abusing the system and voting on questions just because they want to get this badge?

Comment: Absolutely. Anything for the shiny shiny. Is it much of a problem however? Meh, not that sure.

Comment: See also: [The Electorate badge *does* influence voting behaviour in a negative way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87087/the-electorate-badge-does-influence-voting-behaviour-in-a-negative-way)

Comment: +1 so I can get a badge. (Drat! Already had one).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *goal* of the badge is to encourage people to vote on questions more.

Sure, there are people that'll go out of their way to gain badges, but that means the goal of the badge has been reached.

Since you can only vote for any question *once*, and you per-day votes are capped, any 'damage' done is limited. Moreover, it's both voting up *and* down that counts for the badge, so it's not as if we are encouraging people to vote up everything they see.

Are you seeing a lot of votes for questions that do not deserve to be voted on?

Comment: I'm not seeing alot of votes for questions that do not deserve to be voted on but I was wondering as it is easy to get this gold badge not like many others

Comment: @topcat3: People are free to vote as they please, in any case.

Comment: It'd even be hard to say what's a fair/good vote 'cause it's often a matter of ones personal opinion or experiences; in addition, this badge is just one piece in a puzzle that make a whole picture - so I agree here :)