# What is the generic standard for upvoting a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, subjective

I know this is a bit subjective, but I've been thinking and it seems obvious when to upvote or downvote an answer. But what about the question? I mean, some questions are purely self serving and don't really add anything to the community. On the other hand some questions help others, make you think, etc.

I am wondering if there is a generic standard for upvoting questions?

Comment: Someone downvote this for me since I've already spent 30 downvotes today.

Comment: Have you tried hovering the mouse pointer over the arrows? The tooltips are quite helpful.

Comment: By the way the answer to your question is vote however you want, you thoughtless person you.

Comment: Thinking for myself is hard so I'll ask Meta to think for me instead.

Comment: Start with [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64013/why-should-one-vote-on-questions) to know why one should vote on questions. Then, check out [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54914/proper-reasons-to-downvote-a-question-closed) for reasons to downvote questions. Cross validate the contradiction of the second with the results of the first and you'll see why you should upvote. You might also consider reading the negation of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions).

Comment: Or just encourage him to think, Grace. Damn it.

Comment: @Sid I did think about linking [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/how-to-upvote-responsibly/59831#59831), which basically summarizes as "Upvote what you think should be upvoted". But... it was answers.

Comment: I think a better question is why do unclear and not useful questions get upvoted and useful and clear questions stay at 0 votes?

Comment: @Sid - Terrible attitude! Your comments contradict the spirit of SO IMHO.

Comment: @Grace, thanks - that's helpful.

Comment: @java - this is a long standing Welbog pet peeve: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58931/qa-sites-wrongfully-discourage-people-from-thinking-for-themselves-with-respect

Comment: @Sid, I'd like to add that like a troll you use argumentum ad hominem.

Comment: @Jon - I get his point, but IMO he has no right to insult me for asking a question as this regardless of how he feels about it. That right there is blatantly opposite of how the exchange should operate. "Don't like what someone asks" - call em stupid! That'll encourage them to contribute. Jeeze.

Comment: You guys aren't nearly witty enough. No one has voted (up or down) this question, as far as I can see.

Comment: You just proved my point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem#Ad_hominem_abuse

Comment: "You're wrong, blah blah blah" ... "You simpleton"

Comment: Who uses dictionaries these days? Seriously.

Comment: If you don't actually read the things you link then you end up looking foolish. Like just now. I'm given you an opportunity to actually learn what *ad hominem* actually means and you even found a resource that could teach you and yet you still did not learn. Therefore I am justified when I refer to you as an ignoramus. That is not *ad hominem*. You get an F in definitions. If you try really hard and demonstrate that you are capable of *thought* then I might give you a D.

Comment: Asking questions on MSO about how to apply SO-powers is a *good and healthy* thing. Sid Meier is an idiotic, pancake eating Canadian who wouldn't know how to think for himself if you hit him in the face with it. And he's funny looking.

Comment: @Jon: Very good. You've figured out what javamonkey couldn't in a fraction of the time he's had to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I've been wanting to get that out of my system for quite some time now.

Comment: What that in order for you to not attack me I must attack you? Ha.

Comment: Or is this a "don't feed the trolls" meme?

Comment: Strike me down, javamonkey, so that I may rise again more powerful than you could ever imagine!

Comment: The best defense is a good offense.

Comment: I refuse. I choose to turn the other cheek. The fact is, you don't know me. You can call me whatever you want and deduce whatever you think - but the fact remains that you know nothing about me based on one post. I stand by my accusation of ad hominem attack and almost wish there was an English semantics site on the exchange to open the topic for clarity (maybe there is...too lazy at this point to look).

Comment: Also for the record...Jon...I lol'ed thanks.

Comment: Choosing to be wrong even when you have the answer right in front of you is pretty dumb.

Comment: This reminds of the political commercials we all had to endure recently. "Don't vote for Candidate X - he worships the devil and kills babies". Thank you sir, may I have another?

Comment: Finally I was able to downvote you. All's right with the world.

Comment: Good for you. I find happiness in helping others and solving problems. :)

Comment: +2 for the simpleton! I'm back at 0 :P

Answer (score 5):

The tooltip on the upvote arrow is:

> This question is useful and clear

Downvote:

> This question is unclear or not useful

I think that sums it up perfectly.

Personally, I upvote questions when I say to myself "ooh! good question". And I downvote when I think the OP is wasting SO's time.

Comment: This answer is useful (click again to undo)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm being bitter, but as a recipient of the Unsung Hero badge, I wait until an answer gets accepted **and** upvoted before upvoting the question.  Basically, it is an acknowledgement that the question asker knows how to play the game.

Comment: Ha, that's a funny point. Though, I used to think that way - in general if it's somewhat insightful I'll still upvote it.