# Why is "Proper reasons to downvote a question?" closed as duplicate?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

The question [Proper reasons to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54914/proper-reasons-to-downvote-a-question)
is closed as exact duplicate 
of the following question:

[Why do you cast downvotes on answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers)

Without looking at the answers, the questions are definitly different and I just wanted to 
ask myself a similar question.

Please reopen the question  [Proper reasons to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54914/proper-reasons-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: A meta question about a meta question.  *I'm mellltingggg....*

Comment: @Robert Please move to MMSO

Comment: `[status-completed]`

Comment: BTW I would like to know, how a single user with 708 rep was able to close a question. I though it needed 5 users or a moderator.

Comment: He's a mod on SF, and used to have mod abilities here, too.