# How to interpret downvote

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do you cast downvotes on answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers)
>   [Proper reasons to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54914/proper-reasons-to-downvote-a-question)

[I recently got a downvote for a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675917/previous-next-record-based-on-search-result). Now I know this happens constantly, even to people with lots of reputation that are used to asking questions. What I'm after is: Why do you think this one got downvoted? I don't really care on a personal level, or about this question in particular, but as I love a good answer, I'd like to ask as good questions as possible. Both for my self, but also for the benefit of the community.

Please comment on what would make this question better and more relevant for Stack Overflow. Language? Composition? Length?

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that the question seems very much like, "I don't know how to even start to do this; can you just toss some ideas my way?"

Generally speaking, we prefer that you already have done some work toward accomplishing the goal you are seeking, and are here to ask specific questions about problems you are having, rather than more broad, brain-storming sorts of posts.

At least, that's the only thing that immediately pops into my head. Beyond that, the question looks pretty good; you've described your problem and situation fairly well and to a good level of detail. The length isn't a problem, nor language or composition.

But keep in mind that I am only guessing, here. I think you know that, but just to be sure...

Comment: That's a good point indeed. I should focus on making my questions more pointed, so it's easier to come up with a "correct answer". Still not applying to Meta though ;)