# Should I downvote "here is the codez" answers?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Down Vote “code only” answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers)

Related question: [Result of getting next 12 months in Javascript is messed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832179/result-of-getting-next-12-months-in-javascript-is-messed-up)

So far, all the answers just give the code with a little sentence on the side with no comments whatsoever. I see this kind of answers quite often and am wondering: is it legitimate to downvote this kind of answer?

What I mean is that the answer should not just give the code, but it should explain *why* OP was wrong, and *how* to fix it. This kind of answer clearly doesn't help IMHO.

So... just asking what the community thinks of this.

Comment: You should have a look at the "low quality" tab in the review panel... you would get rid of your reputation pretty fast. ;)

Comment: Ugh, didn't look at this. I guess I'm going to be more relaxed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The label on the downvote button reads "This answer is not useful".

So if you think that a plain-code-without-text-answer is not useful, downvote it - if you're ready to pay 1 reputation point for that. But don't downvote just because you expect text. Downvote because the code by itself is really not useful.

Maybe, add a comment explaining the downvote and follow up on the answer in case the answerer does correct it, removing the downvote again.