# Is downvoting an answer that is a single line of code encouraged?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Down Vote “code only” answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers)

Check below answer and the comments:

[How to cast an 'int' to a 'char' in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813412/how-to-cast-an-int-to-char-in-c/10813577#10813577)

That's my first post in SO and it received one up vote and one down vote:

> you can do it as below,
>
> ```
> string justNumbers = new String(text.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
> ```

That code it self explaining what it does if you know C#, and I have also tested it and it's working fine.

Why would a user with 500+ rep behave like this — is this the way of Stack Overflow to welcome new members?