# Notification for answers to merged questions

Tags: feature-request, notifications, merged-questions

[This answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers/134369#134369) was recently moved to a different question via a merge. Now, my answer was a bit more specific to the [original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134367/is-downvoting-an-answer-that-is-a-single-line-of-code-encouraged), and didn't make sense when applied to the newer, more general post.

Now, I never was notified of this merge, so I didn't know it had to be fixed. (OK, I got Necromancer for it, which *should* have made me O_0 since it was a new post, but I usually ignore MSO badge notifications)

[Fortunately, random♦ fixed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/134369/revisions) (along with a random♦ edit summary), and I was notified of the edit.

Couldn't we have notifications for question merges?

Comment: `I usually ignore MSO badge notifications` What?! Heresy!

Comment: @YannisRizos: Too many badges :P I usually go "OK, another badge. w00t!". But I've started ignoring which badge it is :) Too many "nice X", "Enlightened", and "Necromancer" badges.