# Are code-only answers generally disapproved of

Tags: discussion

I voted to close a question that showed little effort, and then realized I previously written a small program which could serve as an illustration of what the question was asking for, and quickly [posted it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16229020/733077).

For a question tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c), it seems perfectly appropriate to answer in C code (particularly as an illustration, rather than a *gime the codez*), but not only was I downvoted and harassed (mildly), but a sound-byte answer gets 8 upvotes! On a close-bait non-constructive question?

I've also noticed a few other users posting code-only answers that receive little attention, even when it *demonstrates* what the English answer only describes.

Confession: I've seen the similar questions, so I expect this to be closed as a dup of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers) probably. But I wanted to tell my story. Thanks for listening.

Comment: You consider `Can you please add some form of description or comment to explain exactly what this is supposed to be showing and doing? Thank you.` Mild harassment?  Really?  That's extremely polite and constructive for a comment and in *no way* is that harassment.

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpreted the 'Thank You.' part. In USA usage, this can often be a rhetorical disparagement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subjectively, there are those who frown upon it and those who take it at face value.

Objectively, a code-only answer can still be a perfectly helpful answer for the OP.

Ideally there should always be something of an explanation of what is going on (some people even annotate their answering code with comments to such effect), and they are often beefed up after satisfying the Fastest Gun criteria. Sometimes they're not revisited by the owner, and then it is at the whim of the community.

The community may down-vote, harass with comments, or if particularly incensed, even flag (the most inappropriate, IMO). Or, they can be constructive and contribute by expanding on the post if they have enough knowledge about what they are complaining about *not* being there. This is where the motives of each individual comes into play - it seems to take a particular kind of person to forego any consideration for themselves and reputation and edit somebody else's answer that they feel is inferior to a standard. This is just a matter of diversity, and we do have lots of good, selfless people here.

Comment: I suppose it was a variation of Fastest Gun. I wanted to get it posted before the remaining closers showed up.

Answer (score 6):

Just as a question that posts code-only and states 'my code doesn't work' isn't really a question, so too is an answer that posts code only.

An answer explains what is wrong and how it can be addressed, using the code as the example.

Code-only answers might be correct and might solve the problem but it's not really helping anyone other than letting them copy and paste the code to use it themselves. A good answer would include the code *and* explain what that code actually does and why it's better that the version posted in the question.

Comment: I'd agree with that in general. Doesn't seem to apply here though, since the question was "Is it possible?".