# Do users get points or something for off voting a question? Because that's all I see here

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

Whenever I ask a question users off vote it or comment about how bad the question is rather than answering it. I see some really experienced users trying to answer but are backed off because of negativity towards the question.

It's not the objective of this site and by introducing that unwanted feature the whole point of having this site has been downgraded.

This will be my last question and appearance on this site and the admins should try to maintain a collection of genuine users rather than some hypocrites who have nothing better to do.

Comment: "I see some really experienced users trying to answer but are backed off because of negativity towards the question." MISSION. ACCOMPLISHED. No, seriously. If the question is bad, it *shouldn't* be answered until it's fixed. Any progress toward not answering lousy questions is *excellent* news.

Comment: "*It's not the objective of this site*"... or perhaps you don't know the objective of this site... it's "to build a repository of high quality Q&A" with *side-effect* of helping the asker.

Answer (score 11):

Please be aware that downvotes are cast for many reasons - see [Why do you cast downvotes on answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers)

There are certainly no points given for downvoting, and in fact users lose reputation for downvoting answers.

The reward for downvoting appropriately comes in seeing questions become better to avoid them, which in turn rewards their askers who get them answered more quickly and comprehensively.

If you have not already seen it, I think understanding the Stack Exchange network, and the way it works, falls into place by reading the section titled **You gotta get this to get us** at [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here).

Answer (score 6):

Users get something that means far more to them than points - they believe they are increasing the quality level of the questions and answers on the site. If a question is missing crucial information, for example, rather than just guessing, or wandering away without answering, they take the time to point out that information is missing. Sometimes they do it super politely and warmly:

> Hey Jim, welcome to StackOverflow! I'd love to help you sort this out, could you just edit your question to include the text of the actual error message? That way I'll know what's wrong. Looking forward to solving this for you!

Other times they're more succinct:

> You didn't include the error message. Nobody can solve this without the message

And sometimes, alas, they're rude:

> What's the error message, dummy? Do you think we're psychic?

But the motivation is the same in every case - to make the question better. And yes, that includes closing questions to prevent answers from being added that would be no more than guesses, or closing questions that are off topic so that other users don't see unrelated material on a site. All of this is done out of a sense of giving and caring - it's just that they are giving and caring to the larger group of "everyone who reads here" more than "one person who has a problem and asked for help."

You can get better at using these sites. It starts with knowing the objective. Downvoting and closing most definitely **do** support the objective of the site, which is to make Q&A better. Excluding low quality contributions, and telling people how to improve the quality of their contributions, are most certainly one way to do that.

There are lots of ways to learn how this works. That will help you feel better (it's not personal) and also get the answers you really need. Finding meta is a first step. I even wrote a course about these sites: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites because I know it's not simple to just "pick up" the culture and the quality norms. Understanding why someone did something you don't like may help you so I've taken the time to explain it in this answer.

Comment: Is it just me or does pluralsight charge money and / or require me to sign up? Because if it does, I'd have to consider this answer (or at least that link) spam... wouldn't want that to happen, would I :)

Comment: Yes, you can buy a subscription to their courses. Or you could watch that one with a free trial. But a quick search here would show you that spam means a post that exists only to promote something paid. I mentioned the course to show that I do know it's not simple and obvious how these sites work. I would never call it obvious or mock someone for not understanding it right away. Agreed?