# Protocol for responding to a hasty-candidate down vote?

Tags: support, comments, down-votes

Situation

1. I posted a question.
2. Fairly quickly, there was a comment "not
   reproducible" and a downvote. On its face, the downvote would appear
   to be from the commenter, and that there was a single attempt to reproduce the problem (which is fair).
3. Comment of "not reproducible" spurred me to branch down that path to find the crux of the answer. And I think I have found the answer (search limits tied to IP addresses) and that the problem is reproducible.
4. Assuming that I have found the answer and post it, then how does the downvote on the question get lifted?

I do want to emphasize that the comment was helpful because it helped me "switch gears" in thinking about the problem. It was just unsettling to have something downvoted because (on its face) a single attempt to reproduce the problem failed.

If it helps, here's the question I posted:
[LinkedIn requiring login even though profile set to OK for public viewing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106470/linkedin-requiring-login-even-though-profile-set-to-ok-for-public-viewing)

Comment: Improve your question!

Comment: That was not a helpful comment.

Comment: @RJo It is helpful because it's the only action that will allow the person who issued the vote to reverse their vote.  If it's not helpful then that is on you

Answer (score 5):

As you will see at [Why do you cast downvotes on answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers) there are many reasons why people downvote.

The protocol I would recommend when you think that one has been hastily applied to your question is to ignore it, and have confidence that a well researched and well presented question will easily receive enough upvotes to offset it and any more that it may garner.

If you suspect your question is not so well researched and presented, then I recommend reflecting on the downvote tooltip of:

> This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not
>   useful.

I would treat any comments that you get that provide further clarification on perceived weaknesses in your question as a bonus.

Comment: It was a downvote on a question, not an answer. And in this case, I'm very certain that clarity of the question was not the issue. Having said that, I do appreciate your time in providing a thoughtful comment. I've also since resolved the problem for the specific question.

Comment: @RJo Most of what applies to answers applies to questions as well, and 
the rest of this advice beyond the first sentence is spot on regardless. Also, lack of clarity is not the only reason for a downvote, as mentioned.